# Is there a 'at the bottom here!' float specifier?

Tags: floats, positioning

For specification of the placement of a float (like a figure or table), one can use 'h' meaning 'here', 't' for 'somewhere at the top of a page' and 'b' for 'somewhere at the bottom of a page'. Is there a way to force a float to be placed 'here, but at the bottom of this page'? A sort of h!b combination.

Comment: There's [b!].  Alternatively, you can look at the `float` package.

Comment: »here, but at the bottom of this page«  Don't these contradict each other?  Use `b!` to force it to the bottom.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/10995)

Comment: In ConTeXt use `\placefigure[bottom,force][<ref>]{<caption>}{<figure>}`.

Comment: @JPi & at Henri: I think !b is the answer concluding from the mandatory reading. If my question is sufficiently different please provide as answer, otherwise flag as duplicate.